# How can I set Heroku config vars programmatically from inside the app running on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I have an app running on Heroku with a small handful of settings that I want to change from time to time, and I'd like to use Heroku config vars to store these settings so they persist durably.

I know I can modify the settings from the Heroku dashboard or the Heroku CLI, but I'd like to modify them from within the app UI.

I can't seem to figure out how to *modify* the app's Heroku config from within the app code. If I simply modify the dyno's environment, for example, those changes do not persist to the app's config.

Comment: If you want to change some variables from time to time you could create a app_setting.rb model with just one db entry.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Heroku Platform API for this. Especially [this part](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#config-vars). There is also a [ruby client](https://github.com/heroku/platform-api)

Comment: Thanks Michał, but then I have to authenticate within the dyno, or put my Heroku API key in the app's env. Is there no way to do this within the app natively?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I asked Heroku support about this 1 or 2 months ago and they said that basically all env variables are readonly. The only way to set them is use ui/api/cli or by exporting them in buildpacks.